# Reduced homology isomorphic to homology relative to a point

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, exact-sequence

I'm going over reduced homology following tom Dieck's *Algebraic Topology*.

I don't understand where the short exact sequence in the excerpt below comes from. $j:(X,\emptyset)\hookrightarrow (X,P)$ is just an inclusion in $\mathsf{Top}^2$. Furthermore, how does $j$ induce those isomorphisms?

[image]